# AngularJS controller resolve: Argument 'controller' is not a function, got Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, requirejs

I am trying to inject an controller into the $routeScope when using AngularJS's $routeprovider and requireJS

```
 $routeProvider.when '/',
        templateUrl : loadView('aboutJellyfish')
        controller: 'aboutJellyfish'
        resolve:
          first:loadController('aboutJellyfish')
```

The loadController function:

```
loadController = (ctrl_name) ->
        resolve = undefined
        resolve = ["$q", "$controller", "$rootScope", "$routeParams", ($q, $controller, $rootScope) ->
          deferred = undefined
          deferred = $q.defer()
          require(["../controllers/" + ctrl_name], (ctrl_module) ->
            $controllerProvider.register(ctrl_name, ctrl_module)
            $rootScope.$apply(->
              deferred.resolve not 0
            )
          )
          deferred.promise
        ]
```

The requirejs configuration:

```
require.config
  paths:
    jQuery: 'lib/jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min'
    angular: 'lib/angular/angular.min'
    app: 'app'

  shim:
    'angular':
      exports : 'angular'
      deps:['jQuery']
    'app':
      deps:['angular']
      exports:'app'
    'jQuery':
      exports : '$'

  priority: ['jQuery','angular','app']
  urlArgs: 'v=1.01'

require ['angular','app'], (angular) ->
  angular.element(document).ready () ->
    angular.bootstrap(document,[applicationName])
```

And the Controller

```
'use strict'
define ['app'],(app) ->
  app.controller 'aboutJellyfish', ['$scope',($scope)=>
    $scope.info='it works!'
  ]
```

The issue is that i get the following error 'Argument 'aboutJellyfish' is not a function, got Object'but using the following piece of code in the Controller everything works fine:

```
'use strict'
define ['app'],(app) ->
  aboutJellyfish = ["$scope", ($scope) ->
    $scope.info="Jellyfish Beta 0.1"
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `loadController('aboutJellyfish')` is returning the actual controller object

```
return resolve = [ "$q", "$controller", "$rootScope", "$routeParams", function($q, $controller, $rootScope)...
```

But `resolve {}` on `$routeProvider` needs to receive a function instead.

```
resolve: {
   first: <- it needs to be a function here
}
```